# White screen on node view or edit in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

[image]

Some of node is not viewing or not editing. Only white screen is coming. I have enabled error from server end too. Also I have added

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

This line of code in index.php

But no error is showing, only white screen is coming.

Comment: Go to "admin/config/development/logging" and check "All messages", refresh your node and when white screen will be display, check "admin/reports/dblog" you should can see your errors.

Answer (score 0):

write these lines in your settings.php of your drupal, may these helps you

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

What `phpinfo()` says? Is error displaying enabled or not?

What do you mean by "on server end"? .htaccess or php.ini ?

Also, check with `phpinfo()` where php error log file is and check if any error is logged there. If error loggin is disabled enable it and then check for logged errors. Check also on apache (or what ever web server you are using) error log. It may happen that there is no error in code, but some trivial reason caused this, like lack of memory, disk space...

Also check for some dead loops, endless recursions or similar never ending code..

Drupal reports / error loging can help too (as @lamp5 suggested).

Another thing if server didn't return any body (white screen) it did return some response code, so check on that too. Use some tool, for this, browser inspection tools, Postman app or similar.

Comment: Yes it is enabled from server. I mean from php.ini. Please check my added image.